# how to vertically center text with li element when flexbox is used?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following menubar:

```
<ul>
    <li><a>A</a></li>
    <li><a>B</a></li>
    <li><a>C</a></li>
</ul>
```

And the following CSS:

```
ul { display: flex; flex-direction: row; height: 100%; }
ul li { flex: 1, auto; text-align: center; }
ul li a:hover { cursor: pointer; }
```

I do this so that the padding-left between li is the same. But now it is difficult to vertically center the text. Is there any suggestion?

I have tried to add line-height: 2 in li. But I don't think it is the solution.

Thank you.

Comment: If line-height works fine, why not use it?

Comment: I edited my answer as to your question.  Your 'ul' is height 50px.  Your 'ul li' has line-height: 50px.  It will center. Check out the 'Run Code Snippet' again please.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

**HTML** (no changes)

```
<ul>
    <li><a>A</a></li>
    <li><a>B</a></li>
    <li><a>C</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body { height: 100%; } /* necessary if using percentage heights on child elements */

ul {
    display: flex; /* establish flex container */
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0; /* for demo purposes */
    margin: 0; /* for demo purposes */
    background-color: #eaeaea; /* for demo purposes */
    border: 5px solid black;  /* for demo purposes */
    font-size: 2em;  /* for demo purposes */
}

ul li {
    flex: 1; /* distribute all available space evenly among flex items */
    margin: 10px;  /* for demo purposes */
    border: 2px dashed red;  /* for demo purposes */
    display: flex; /* make each flex item a flex container, as well */
    align-items: center; /* center text vertically (in this case) */
    justify-content: center;  /* center text horizontally (in this case) */
}

ul li a:hover { 
    cursor: pointer;
    }
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/vfa01j14/

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is using `display: table-cell`. Try the snippet below:

```css
ul li {
    height: 50px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    border: 1px solid lightblue;
}
ul li a:hover { 
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a>A</a></li>
    <li><a>B</a></li>
    <li><a>C</a></li>
</ul>
```

You can try adding different height to test it out, and it will work if you don't set the height (cause you may not know it) it will automatically align content vertically.

Comment: no. i don't want to use fixed height 50px. i am using percentage height. if i can use fixed height, then the answer is too obvious for me to ask here. sorry.

Comment: well, let me fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Your css code above gave me a totally different alignment than you describe above.  Menus run into each other.  Why wouldn't you just use `display: block/inline-block` as follows?

I added 50px height to ul and 50px to ul li.  To keep menu items separate, I added margin-left: 2px;

```css
ul {   
  display: block;
  flex-direction: row; 
  height: 50px;
}
ul li { 
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  display: inline-block;
  flex: 1, auto;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  text-align: center; 
}
ul li a:hover { 
  cursor: pointer; 
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a>A</a></li>
    <li><a>B</a></li>
    <li><a>C</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what if `li` has height of, lets say, `50px`. This is not a solution

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
 ul { 
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 50px; 
}
ul li { 
    flex: 1, auto;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    border: 1px solid lightblue;
}
ul li a:hover { 
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/5ckpm9ba/1/)

Comment: no luck. why display:block when flex-direction: row?

Answer (score 0):

If you fix the height of "ul", you can easily make the 'li' vertically centered by applying these CSS

```css
ul {   
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

ul li { 
  background-color:lightblue;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center; 
  position:relative;
  top: 50%;
    -moz-transform: translatey(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translatey(-50%);
    -o-transform: translatey(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translatey(-50%);
    transform: translatey(-50%);
}

ul li a:hover { 
  cursor: pointer; 
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a>A</a></li>
    <li><a>B</a></li>
    <li><a>C</a></li>
</ul>
```